# how to validate a select field in jquery?

Tags: jquery, validation, select

I have this code:

```
<form action="" id="credentials" method="post">
<label for="name" id="nameLabel" >Name*:</label>
<input type="text" name="name" id="name" value=""  />
<select id="single">
   <option value="0">Single</option>
   <option value="1">Single2</option>
</select>
<input type="submit" value="Submit" name="" data-inline="true"/>
</form>
```

And I'm trying to validate like this:

```
$("#credentials").submit(function(e) {
    var nameField = $("input#name").filter(function() {
        return !$.trim(this.value).length;
    });

    if (nameField.length) {
        nameField.css("border", "1px solid red");
        alert("Name is missing!");

        return false;
    }

    var stateField = $("#single").val();

    if (stateField == 0) {
        stateField.css("border", "1px solid red");
        alert("State is missing!");
        return false;
    }
});
```

The input is working fine, but not the select. Any ideas? Here is a [JSFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/patrioticcow/A6eEh/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that your `stateField` variable holds the actual value of the field. It is not a reference to the field itself or a jQuery object for the field so you can't say `stateField.css()`.

Try something like this:

```
var stateField = $("#single");

if (stateField.val() == 0) {
    stateField.css("border", "1px solid red");
    alert("State is missing!");
    return false;
}
```

Updated version of your demo: http://jsfiddle.net/A6eEh/3/

Note also that by returning from your function as soon as you find an error your validation will only ever report one error at a time (so the `stateField` validation won't occur unless you've entered a name).

Answer (score 2):

Updated jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/A6eEh/2/

stateField is only holding the value not the actual element. You need to apply the css to the element